# Unable to append data in my component vuejs

Tags: jquery, vuejs2

I have div with some data of 20 records i have setup onscroll more data every thing is working fine except data append in that div.

```
<script>
    methods: {
        loadMoreTimeline: function (event){
                let uri = route('contact.get.timeline', {
                listuid: this.listuid,
                subscriberuid: this.subscriberuid
            });

            axios.get(uri+"?offset"+offset).then(resp => {
                console.log('Timeline response: ', resp);

                if(resp.length == 0)
                    return false;


                this.data.push(this.resp);
            });
        },
        handleScroll: function (event){
          var currentScrollPosition = event.srcElement.scrollTop;
            if (currentScrollPosition > this.scrollPosition) {
                if((currentScrollPosition+800) >= event.srcElement.scrollHeight && loading == 0){
                    loading = 1;
                    // event.srcElement.append();
                    this.loadMoreTimeline();
                    console.log('Load More');
                }

            }
            this.scrollPosition = currentScrollPosition; 
        },
        created: function () {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
        },
        destroyed: function () {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
        }

}
```

my component:

```
<div class="events-holder" @scroll="handleScroll">
                <div class="timeline-event animated fadeInDown" :class="[isActive(item), item.type]" v-for="item in data"
                    :key="item.id" @click="setActive(item)" v-if="item.type">
                    <!-- more code -->
</div>
</div>
```

Every thing working perfect data fetching on scroll etc only issue i am facein that how to append that data in my div

Answer (score 1):

In Vue, or other SPA frameworks, you don't need to (and shouldn't try to) manually append any information to the DOM; it's all done by manipulating the component data and letting the framework do the work of updating the page.

You haven't shown the full component with its initial data, so I may be off here, but it looks like in `loadMoreTimeline()` you're treating the component's data block as a single array, pushing directly onto it:

```
 this.data.push(this.resp);
```

But the `v-for` in the template is instead iterating over an array named data *inside* the component's data block:

```
 v-for="item in data"
```

...which implies that the line in  `loadMoreTimeline()` should actually be `this.data.data.push(this.resp)`.   (Which would work, but you probably should choose a less confusing name for that array; `this.data.items` and `v-for="item in items"`, perhaps.)

Once you're pushing the new information on to the correct array, it should Just Work -- `push()` is one of the mutation methods Vue [wraps in observers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection) -- so it shouldn't be necessary to use `Vue.set` or `vm.$set` to make the new data reactive.

Comment: getting this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`  when i did that `this.data.data.push(this.resp)`

Comment: OK, that suggests you haven't got an array named `data` inside the component's data block; but in that case I can't see why your `v-for` would be working at all, since as written that's what it would be referencing.  Can you post your complete component (including its initial `data` section)?